# Comparison of JSON arrays Angular 6

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have two different JSON objects :

```
a = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"2",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"},{id:"5",time:"timestamp"}];
b = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"}];
```

I want to create a new array based on matching from array a. for example the output in the above example looks like this :

```
c = ["1","0","1","1","0"]
```

where 1 is for the case where we find the id and 0 is when we dont get the id.

So far I tried this :

```js
c = [];

var val = JSON.parse(b);
if (val.length > 0) {
  val.forEach((obj) => {
    var match = a.find(({
      id
    }) => obj.id === id);
    if (!match) {
      c.push("0");
    } else {
      c.push("1");
    }
  });
}
console.log(c);
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong in this.

Thanks

Comment: What does that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you should do it the other way around. If you want to check if the values of the first list are in the second, you need to loop on the first list and not the second.

```
c = [];

    var val = JSON.parse(a);
    if( val.length > 0 ) {
       val.forEach((obj)=>{
         var match = b.find(({id}) => obj.id === id);
         if(!match){
           c.push("0");
         }
         else {
           c.push("1");
         }
       });
    }
    console.log(c);
```

Comment: Yes, I now see the problem, Thanks @ukn

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `forEach` with `a` then find an element in `b`.

```js
var a = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"2",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"},{id:"5",time:"timestamp"}];
var b = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"}];

var c = [];
var val = a;

if (val.length > 0) {
  val.forEach((obj) => {
    var match = b.find(({
      id
    }) => obj.id === id);
    if (!match) {
      c.push("0");
    } else {
      c.push("1");
    }
  });
}
console.log(c);
```

Comment: This is perfect, I guess this is the best way. Thanks @zmag

Answer (score 1):

Use Simple `For` loop;

```js
 a = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"2",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"},{id:"5",time:"timestamp"}];
    b = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"}];

    var arr  = [];
    var a_keys =  a.map(e => e.id);
    var b_keys =  b.map(e => e.id);
    
    for(var i=0;i<a_keys.length;i++){
        if(b_keys.indexOf(a_keys[i]) != -1){
           arr.push('1');
       }else{
       arr.push('0');
       }
    }

    console.log(arr);
```

```js
a = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"2",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"},{id:"5",time:"timestamp"}];
    b = [{id:"1",time:"timestamp"},{id:"3",time:"timestamp"},{id:"4",time:"timestamp"}];

    var arr  = [];

    
    for(var i= 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(var j= 0; j < b.length; j++) {
         if(a[i].id ===  b[j].id){
          arr.push('1');
          break;
         }
         if((a[i].id !==  b[j].id) && (j === (b.length - 1))){
             arr.push('0');
         }
       }
     }

    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This would increase the complexity @Mahi the better way is not to iterate that way for larger arrays.